# Executing a PHP file from a jQuery / AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm making a chat function where staff members with the appropriate privileges can delete a line that has been posted to the chat room.

I'd like this function to work without refreshing the page, but I can't seem to get the jQuery / AJAX part of it right? Nothing happens at all.

As a jQuery newbie I was hoping that someone could point out the line that I'd have to look at?

a href that needs to be clicked to delete line:

```
for (var i in json.lines) {
    lines.push("[<a class='delete' href='#' data-lineID='" + json.lines[i].id + "'>x</a>] " + json.lines[i].user + json.lines[i].divide + " " + json.lines[i].message);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a.delete').on('click', function(event) {
var id = $(this).data('lineID');

    /* Request to .php file */
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/communications/chat.php?page=delete",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : id },
    dataType: "html"
    });

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
```

});

Part of the PHP script to execute:

```
case 'delete' :

if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    try {
        $query = $udb->prepare("UPDATE `chat_lines` SET `deleted` = '1' WHERE `id` = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1,$id);
        $query->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

break;
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You cannot delete the line from the clients who now have them on the screen without pushing a script to each client

Comment: can you please turn on your javascript console and take a look at the request being sent and what is actually passed to the php page?

Comment: Hi mplungjan - The chat is run with JSON so auto-updates on the screen without the user having to refresh, so the line will disappear for all users when an admin deletes the line. As mentioned above, I'm just looking for the reason as to why the jQuery is not running as required.

Comment: @tampe125, I'm fairly new to JavaScript, jQuery & AJAX, so unfortunately I don't know what you mean :(

Comment: Please take a look at here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers . Open it *before* clicking on the link. Click the link, you should see the AJAX request being performed wit the actual data sent

Comment: @tampe125, I think I may have done something very wrong, as I've just done hat and nothing appears. The console stays empty :-/

Comment: the "Delete" button is there when the page loads or is dynamically added?

Comment: The button is a hyperlinked letter x inside square brackets. It's displayes next to every line and the data-lineID would be unique to the line that the [x] is next to.

Comment: if you put an ugly `alert('xx')` inside the javascript code, is it triggered?

Comment: No. And the console still doesn't show anything happening :-/ Hoever, the JSON that's above it to load the chat lines every 5 seconds and submit new lines is working without an issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a long shot, but I think that your issue is caused by HTML element not being there when you load the Javascript.
jQuery will attach an event listener (in this case the `click` one) when the script is loaded.
If the element is added *after* the script loads, the listener is not attached so it won't trigger your code.

What you have to do is to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This means that you have to change your javascript code to this:

```
$('#mainContainerOfYourChat').on('click', 'a.delete', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('lineID');

    /* Request to .php file */
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/communications/chat.php?page=delete",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id : id },
            dataType: "html"
        });

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

In this way jQuery will listen to the main container of your page, when a click is fired, if it matches the `a.delete` selector, it will trigger your code.

Comment: Well, this is some sort of progress I guess. It's now displaying the following in the JavaScript Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: there was a typo, please review the code: Stack Overflow is not the best way to write code :D

Comment: use $(this).attr('data-lineID') instead of $(this).data('lineID')

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is deleting the post from the DB your only problem is it stays loaded on the client side until you reload the page.
If that is so you'll only need to include a line to remove the comment if the ajax call is successful:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/communications/chat.php?page=delete",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : id },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(){
      $("a.delete[data-lineID="+id+"]").parent().remove();
     }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the chat is auto updated for all users with JSON. The issue is when I click the 'x' link for the jQuery to run the PHP script which updates the DB, nothing happens. The row in the DB remains unaffected.

Comment: check out (with an alert for ex.) does the code reach your php function at all, also try to get any error messages (fireBug is what I use)